# Where are Linker Flags in External C Library?

Tags: xcode, cmake

I have a C library which I need to use in my ongoing Xcode project. I used Cmake to build and install that Library. I gave the paths to Headers files and I can include the files into my Xcode project. However, when I run the project it says:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I suspect that problem is with Linker Flags. I haven't included any Linker Flags and I don't know which flags do I need to add. Please tell me where in the library would I get all the required Linker Flags.

git hub link of the library which I want to add:
https://github.com/cbalint13/pba

Comment: Message `linker command failed with exit code 1` may mean **anything**: missed library, unresolved symbol, incompatible libriaries. First thing you need to know - **actual** error which cause linker to fail. That error should be shown above the "linker command failed" message.

Answer (score 1):

From xcode left side window.

Under Project Navigator, click on your project, click on build settings.

Select "All" and "Combined" sections, then search for "Linker Flag"

Don't forget to switch to your target's build settings as well. As you might change just the "Project", not the "Target".

Comment: I know where to add Linker flags in Xcode project settings. I need to know what Linker Flags do I need to add.

Comment: @RaghavGoyal Sorry that I misread your question, as per the comment in your question, it could mean anything. I once had that linker problem, then I tried messing around with different flags. Instead of solving, it creates more problems. In the end, it was a simple mistake for not including the framework into the main project, something like that. Try checking project settings and make sure everything is linked.